# How to push the artifacts into docker image in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, ant, java

How can i create a docker image of the artifacts using docker instruction. I am using "Build Inside a docker container" in jenkins job.
This is the instruction in the dockerfile:

```
 install openjdk 8`RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;`
```

Then I need to control back to Jenkins job to perform the Build process.
 So in Build process in jenkins Job, "Execute Shell" commands are executed and artifacts are created.
It has some post build action to run the junit test cases and run coverage report.
In the end, I need the dockerfile to run the instruction to create image of the artifacts.
Add sourcefile destinationfile
Please suggest how to write docker instruction to give the control to jenkins job and get the control after build process is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin) to do this (see `docker` object)

```
node("docker") {
    docker.withRegistry('<<your-docker-registry>>', '<<your-docker-registry-credentials-id>>') {

        git url: "<<your-git-repo-url>>", credentialsId: '<<your-git-credentials-id>>'

        sh "git rev-parse HEAD > .git/commit-id"
        def commit_id = readFile('.git/commit-id').trim()
        println commit_id

        def app;
        stage("build") {
            app = docker.build "your-project-name"
        }

        stage("publish") {
            app.push 'master'
            app.push "${commit_id}"
        }
    }
}
```